# How to grab selected HTML from browser and pull into my app

Tags: cocoa, service, sandbox, xpc

I'd like to create a Cocoa app that is able to grab selected text from a website in a third-party browser (in other words, NOT from an embedded webkit instance running within my own app) and then store it in my app's database. From what I can tell, I need to user some kind of service for this, like how selected text in Textedit can be turned into a new sticky note via a service. However, I'd like to be able to provide this app through the App Store. Does that mean I need to use XPC services?

That's as far as I have gotten. So if I do need to use XPC services, can someone point me in a helpful direction? The [Services Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/SysServices.pdf) is totally over my head.

Comment: The third-party browser is going to have to have some functionality that delivers HTML from a window to you.  This is certainly possible if you're writing a browser plug-in *in addition* to your own app. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: I could do it that way, but what about creating a service (like the one I referenced in Textedit)?